# Word for a value incremented by certain amount?

Tags: expressions, mathematics, numbers

*When we take a number and multiply it by 10 we get **a value ten times the original**.*

Then, what do we call the result of adding 10 to a previous value?

i.e., what can I put in place of the ellipsis in the following statement?

`When we add 10 to a number we get a value ... the original`

Comment: "We get a value *ten more than* the original."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your original sentence, I would just say "*a value* **ten greater than** *the original*".

Comment: I thought about that but saying `ten greater (or more) than the original` sounds a little bit weird to me. But you got the idea. Thanks.